# Security Issues: Connect to MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am confused. I want to ask, do I have to enable ssl when connecting to mysql using pdo even though my website already has a secure connection (https)?

Comment: The SSL connection between the browser and your website over HTTPS terminates at your webserver. The connection between the webserver and the database is separate, done on a different port using a different protocol. If the webserver and database are on different machines, and/or the connection will pass through an untrusted network then you may want to consider using a secure connection for that, yes.

Comment: The setup process is separate. I'm not familiar with it but a quick google for "pdo mysql ssl" reveals a few useful looking results, including https://www.saotn.org/how-to-use-ssl-in-php-data-objects-pdo-mysql/